# My Greasemonkey script won't install

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm going to write a small Greasemonkey script.
Here is my test code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name test
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @namespace brak
// @description test
// @include http://forum.php.pl/*
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function(){
alert("OK");
});
```

But it doesn't work.

I tried downloading some random script from *userscripts.org* and it worked when I installed it from the website. But, when I put the source code into `script.js` file and then clicked "Add a new script" - it did not.

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

> when I put the source code into script.js file and then clicked "Add a new script" - it did not.

The filename must end with `.user.js`.  So rename your test file to `test.user.js` or something.  Then you will be able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing

```
// @include <a href="http://forum.php.pl/*" target="_blank">http://forum.php.pl/*</a>
```

To:

```
// @include http://forum.php.pl/*
```

Comment: hmm, the stackoverflow script did it automatically... idk how did it happen..
anyway - in my script I try to install there's everything properly 
with @include etc.