# How do I add a userscript installation button to my web page?

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I need to host a userscript on an internal company website. How do I build the `href` so that Greasemonkey will install the userscript when the link is clicked?

I tried a simple `<a href="user.js">Install Userscript</a>` but Chrome and Firefox simply show the file source instead of installing the userscript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Greasemonkey script won't install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976157/my-greasemonkey-script-wont-install)

Comment: @the8472, Not really a duplicate.  That other guy was asking about a local cut-and-paste.  IIRC, he was trying to make local changes to someone else's script, not host his own.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your link should look like:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/your_script.user.js">Click to install script X</a>
<small>(A userscript engine, like Tampermonkey, is required.)</small>
```

---

In order for your install link to work, the following conditions must be met:

1. The filename must end in `.user.js`. Example: `stack_exchange_edit_reasoner.user.js`
2. The browser must be *running* a compatible userscript extension. For example, *Tampermonkey* or *Greasemonkey*.
3. The file must [NOT be served with `text/html` content type](https://wiki.greasespot.net/User_Script_Hosting#The_Whole_Internet).  (You would have to tamper with your server's default settings for this to be an issue.)

Also, if you wish for automatic updates to work, the script should be served via an `https` link (or it gets complicated).

Comment: The dot before the user.js is what I was missing. Thanks!